# Belongs_to presence in Rails 5 not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, ruby-on-rails-5

To my knowledge, the new default in Rails 5 requires `belongs_to` associations to be present. I made a model with this association, but the problem is I don't get presence validation error when the associated field is empty. Instead I get a database Null Validation error since I set the `_id` column not to be null. (PG::NotNullViolation because I use Postgres)

Is this behaviour normal? I mean shouldn't I get the rails error only?

BTW, when I add presence validation for the field, it works as I expected.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

According to the issue re [weird behaviour of config belongs_to_required_by_default](https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/23589), it seems like one of your other gems intervenes in `ActiveRecord::Base` and causes the bug.

One of workarounds to the issue is to move the line

```
config.active_record.belongs_to_required_by_default = true
```

from initializers directly into `application.rb`.

This worked for me smoothly.

Comment: You don't need to do anything if you have Rails 5.1. Just make sure `config.load_defaults 5.1` is in your application.rb, which is the default for new generated apps ([reference](https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/23589#issuecomment-305557647))

Comment: I set `ActiveRecord::Base.belongs_to_required_by_default = false` in my initializer

Comment: FYI You could also set `belongs_to_required_by_default = false` in your `ApplicationRecord`

Answer (score 3):

New Rails 5 applications come with a new initializer in

```
config/initializers/active_record_belongs_to_required_by_default.rb
```

If you upgraded a Rails 4 application or created your application with a beta version of Rails 5, then that file might be missing.

The configuration in that file enables the feature in question:

```
# Be sure to restart your server when you modify this file.

# Require `belongs_to` associations by default. This is a new Rails 5.0
# default, so it is introduced as a configuration option to ensure that apps
# made on earlier versions of Rails are not affected when upgrading.
Rails.application.config.active_record.belongs_to_required_by_default = true
```

Please check how `belongs_to_required_by_default` is configured in your application.

Comment: `Rails.application.config.active_record.belongs_to_required_by_default = true` is still in the project's `new_framework_defaults.rb`. So I suppose it's not the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I faced with same problem.

You can move

`config.active_record.belongs_to_required_by_default = false`

to `config/environments/needed_environment.rb` or to `config/application.rb`

Helped for me!