# Rails 5 belongs_to default behavior

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, rails-activerecord

```
begin
  require "bundler/inline"
rescue LoadError => e
  $stderr.puts "Bundler version 1.10 or later is required. Please update your Bundler"
  raise e
end

gemfile(true) do
  source "https://rubygems.org"
  gem "rails", github: "rails/rails"
  gem "sqlite3"
end

require "active_record"
require "minitest/autorun"
require "logger"

# This connection will do for database-independent bug reports.
ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection(adapter: "sqlite3", database: ":memory:")
ActiveRecord::Base.logger = Logger.new(STDOUT)

ActiveRecord::Schema.define do
  create_table :posts, force: true do |t|
  end

  create_table :comments, force: true do |t|
    t.integer :post_id
  end
end

class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
end

class Comment < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :post
end

class BugTest < ActiveSupport::TestCase
  def test_association_stuff
    post = Post.create!

    comment = Comment.create
    assert_not_empty comment.errors.full_messages
  end
end
```

This test fails with current rails master.
I think it should succeed since `belongs_to` required by default from Rails 5.

- http://blog.bigbinary.com/2016/02/15/rails-5-makes-belong-to-association-required-by-default.html
- [Belongs_to presence in Rails 5 not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38157293/belongs-to-presence-in-rails-5-not-working)

Is this expected behavior?

Comment: My expectation that test should succeed was wrong since I use #create! instead of #create.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are right, `belongs_to` is required by default in *Rails 5*. In your example, you are not running a *Rails 5* app, you are just using `ActiveRecord`.

`belongs_to` is required by default in Rails 5 because when you generate a new Rails 5 app, you get a file `config/initializers/new_framework_defaults.rb` which has the following line:

```
# Require `belongs_to` associations by default. Previous versions had false.
Rails.application.config.active_record.belongs_to_required_by_default = true
```

To achieve similar results in your example, you have to set this config option for `ActiveRecord` as well (by default it's not set, which means it's `nil`, aka falsy value):

```
# This connection will do for database-independent bug reports.
ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection(adapter: "sqlite3", database: ":memory:")
ActiveRecord::Base.logger = Logger.new(STDOUT)
ActiveRecord::Base.belongs_to_required_by_default = true # <-- This line :)
```

Now if you run your tests, they will pass.

For more info, reference [this pull request](https://github.com/rails/rails/pull/18937/files).